# How to fix 'Run-time error 91 : "Object variable or with block variable not set " using vba Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small section of code to automate a logon to a specific website that sometimes works and sometimes gives the runtime error 91, saying object variable or with block variable not set. How do I fix this problem?

```
Sub AutoLogin()
    Const Url = "https://www.tymetrix360.com/Common/Pages/LoginPage.aspx? 
ReturnUrl=%2f"

    Dim userName As String, password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    userName = LoginData.Cells(1, "A").Value
    password = LoginData.Cells(2, "A").Value

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


        ie.navigate Url
        ie.Visible = True

        ieBusy ie

        ie.Document.all.Item("LoginTextBox").Value = userName
        ie.Document.all.Item("PasswordTextBox").Value = password

        ie.Document.all.Item("LoginButton").Click

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? I'm presuming it's the line where you are setting username?

Comment: Both these lines:    @Zac
ie.Document.all.Item("LoginTextBox").Value = userName
ie.Document.all.Item("PasswordTextBox").Value = password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about checking if the element exists on the page by testing if an object is created?

So `Set user_id_element = ie.document.getElementById("user_id")` then check `IsObject(user_id_element)` and if it is continue, if it is not then loop until present? would be advisable to have some sort of exit conditions in case it never becomes present.

something like this:

```
Sub AutoLogin()
    Const Url = "https://www.campus.ie.edu"

    Dim userName As String, password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    userName = LoginData.Cells(1, "A").Value
    password = LoginData.Cells(2, "A").Value

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


        ie.navigate Url
        ie.Visible = True

        ieBusy ie

        Debug.Print ie.locationurl
        If InStr(1, ie.locationurl, "portal") > 0 Then
            'Already logged in
        Else
            'Need to log in
            Do While Not IsObject(ie.document.getElementById("user_id"))
                'Check if the element is present, otherwise loop and wait
                ieBusy ie
            Loop

            ie.document.getElementById("user_id").Value = userName
            ie.document.all.Item("password").Value = password

            'One way or another submit the form
            'ie.document.getElementById("password").Focus
            'Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'Submit form

            ie.document.forms("login").submit
            'ie.Document.getelementbyid("login").Click
        End If

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Great to hear @DidaW and thank you for marking this as the correct solution :)